# Vectorial height of a triangle

Tags: vectors

[image]

I personally couldn't figure out how $\overrightarrow{\mathrm{h}}_1$ was derived. Any help would be very much appreciated.

$A$ part is understood which is the area of the triangle.

Extended question

Further how to find a point on $\overrightarrow{\ell}_2$ when given ${h_1}$. I have commented a method but not sure whether it's correct or not.

Comment: Lot's of undefined symbols there, but maybe it's just that the area $A'$ of a triangle is half the base $\ell_1'$ times the height $h_1'$?

Comment: $A^\prime$ is the area of the triangle, which I have checked numerically. $\mathrm{h}^\prime_1$ is the height of the triangle but how it is derived is something I can't figure out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prime “ ‘ “ notation for magnitudes is just a complication. I have not used it. Also the “^” notation for vector is misleading because it usually is associated with a vector of magnitude 1. I prefer the regular vector notation.

You have a mistake for area. The correct formula is:

Area $A=\frac{\vec{n}\cdot (\vec {l_2}\times \vec {l_3})}{2}$

This formula of area accounts for:

1. $\vec n$ is the normal vector to the plane of the triangle and its magnitude $||\vec n||=n=1$
2. Furthermore, since $\vec{l_2}\times \vec{l_3}$ results in a vector parallel to $\vec n$, then the dot product is needed to have the resulting area A as a number instead of a vector.
3. You can have the cross product of any pair of different  vectors $\vec{l_1}$, $\vec{l_2}$, $\vec{l_3}$ in the formula of the area: $A=\frac{\vec{n}\cdot (\vec {l_2}\times \vec {l_3})}{2}=\frac{\vec{n}\cdot (\vec {l_3}\times \vec {l_1})}{2}=\frac{\vec{n}\cdot (\vec {l_1}\times \vec {l_2})}{2}$

Then the area can be expressed as $\frac{base \cdot height}{2}$ which in terms of vectors, given that base and height are perpendicular:

$A=\frac{\vec n\cdot(\vec{h_1}\times \vec{l_1})}{2}=\frac{n \cdot h_1 \cdot l_1 \cdot sin(90^ \circ)}{2}=\frac{1\cdot h_1 \cdot l_1 \cdot 1}{2}\Rightarrow h_1=\frac{2A}{l_1}=\frac{2A}{l_1}\cdot\vec{l_1}\times \vec n$

At the last equality I’ve considered that $\vec{l_1}\times \vec n=||\vec{l_1}||\cdot||\vec n || \cdot sin(\vec{l_1},\vec n)=l_1 \cdot 1\cdot sin(90^ \circ)=l_1$

Comment: Any reason why $\mid\, \mid^2$ is preferred than just the base $\overrightarrow{\ell}_1$ ?

Comment: You’re pointing a mistake in my answer. $\frac{1}{l_1}=\frac{||\vec{l_1}||}{{l_1}^2}$, leading to $h_1=\frac{2A}{l_1}\cdot ||\vec{l_1}\times \vec n ||$

Comment: In the updated picture you don’t use brackets for cross product in the formula of A. As for $\vec{h_1}$, is a matter of $\pm$ to account for the indeterminate direction of $\vec{l_1}$.

Comment: That's norm square of $\ell_1$ in $h_1$.

Comment: How to find a point on $\overrightarrow{\mathrm{\ell}_2}$ when $h_1$ is given? Will taking $\hat{n} \cdot \left(\overrightarrow{\ell_2} \times \hat{h}_1\right)$ and mutiply with $h_1$ works? If so, how?

Comment: Any help will be appreciated.